# How to change constant value in a Karma test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have an Angular directive which sets the value of some `$scope` property based on the value of an injected constant.  I want to test that this value is being correctly initialized from the constant, so I would like to change the constant's value within an individual `it` block. (Preferably within one, but changing the value between multiple blocks would be OK too)

Is this possible, and how can I do it?

simplified example:

```
//////// directive ////////
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
.constant('THE_CONSTANT', 'hello world')
.directive('myDirective', ['THE_CONSTANT', function (THE_CONSTANT) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function ($scope) {
            $scope.propertyBasedOnConstant = THE_CONSTANT;
        }
    };
}]);

//////// test ////////
describe('myDirective', function () {
    var $element, $scope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp.directives'));

    beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.constant('THE_CONSTANT', 'foo');
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        $scope = $rootScope;
        $element = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>');
        $compile($element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
    }));

    afterEach(function () {
        $scope.$destroy();
        $element.remove();
    });

    it("should correctly reflect the constant's value", function() {
        expect( $scope.propertyBasedOnConstant ).to.equal('foo');

        // now I want to change the constant's value and re-initialize the directive
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are providing the `constant` into an `undefined` module.

Change your beforeEach block to something like this and it *should just work™*:

```
var $scope, $element, MOCKED_CONSTANT;

beforeEach(function () {
  MOCKED_CONSTANT = 'foo';

  module('myApp.directives', function ($provide) {
    $provide.constant('THE_CONSTANT', MOCKED_CONSTANT);
  });

  inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    $scope       = $rootScope.$new(); // Don't forget to call .$new()!
    var template = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive');
    $element     = $compile(template)($scope); // Store the reference to the compiled element, not the raw string.
    $scope.$digest();
  });
});

it("should correctly reflect the constant's value", function() {
  expect( $scope.propertyBasedOnConstant ).to.equal(MOCKED_CONSTANT);
  // expect( $scope.propertyBasedOnConstant ).to.equal('foo');
});
```

---

If you need to change the constant's value between `it`'s, I would extract the call to `module` into a helper function, aswell as the `inject`. Such as:

```
function setupModule (constant) {
  module('myApp.directives', function ($provide) {
    $provide.constant('THE_CONSTANT', constant);
  });
}

function injectItAll () {
  inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    $scope       = $rootScope.$new(); // Don't forget to call .$new()!
    var template = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive');
    $element     = $compile(template)($scope); // Store the reference to the compiled element, not the raw string.
    $scope.$digest();
  });
}
```

And then in your spec you would do:

```
it('equals banana', function () {
  setupModule('banana');
  injectItAll();
  expect($scope.propertyBasedOnConstant).to.equal('banana');
});
```

Comment: Pulling out the stuff in the beforeEach was exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By definition a constant is an identifier with an associated value which cannot be changed. Instead of changing the constant value why not inject the constant itself and use it within your expectations.

```
describe('myDirective', function () {
    var $element, $scope,
      THE_CONSTANT;

    beforeEach(module('myApp.directives'));

    beforeEach(module(function (_THE_CONSTANT_) {
      THE_CONSTANT = _THE_CONSTANT_;
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        $scope = $rootScope;
        $element = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>');
        $compile($element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
    }));

    afterEach(function () {
        $scope.$destroy();
        $element.remove();
    });

    it("should correctly reflect the constant's value", function() {
        expect( $scope.propertyBasedOnConstant ).to.equal(THE_CONSTANT);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Because I have different sets of expectations based on the value of the constant, and I'd like to test each of them.  I understand that a constant cannot change within the lifetime of the app, so I'd need to re-$provide and re-initialize...but how?

Comment: Can you provide a use case wherein there are different values that can be provided to a constant? perhaps there is a better approach to solve this problem. Its also possible to solve this problem if you were to use a `.value()` instead of a `.constant()`.

Comment: My example is so contrived I'm not sure what a use case could add...basically the constant is just one of the inputs to my directive, and I want to test that different values of that input are consumed correctly.  Say that if `MY_CONSTANT == 'bar'` then `propertyBasedOnConstant` should be "BAR" not "bar" (see? seems silly).  I'm getting the sense that my original ask isn't possible though, so I will think about alternatives.